# How to display text in flutter so that RTL language is aligned right and LTR is aligned left?

Tags: text, flutter, dart, right-to-left, left-to-right

Basically i want to display pre-formatted text in a flutter application.
I am using flutter_markdown. This is the closest thing i found that works for me(I have tried almost all widget of text like rich text. Also breaking of paragraphs into multiple string to format  differently is tedious work).
In a multi-line multi paragraph i have formatted text resource in both RTL and LTR language.

But the problem is that my LTR languages are fine but RTL languages are getting aligned left whereas it should be aligned on right side. 
I want to display the content formatted in original way (Usually i format it on MS Word and paste as string resource). If there is any other option beside fluter_markdown to solve my problem it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I Thing that you make a custom widget one for rtl and one for Ltr so
every time you need rtl call the rtl and when call ltr get of lte content.